# Javascript code seems to execute many times, why?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I try to insert Wordpress shortocde in tinyMCE editor via button, an I have a little problem. Script insert shortcode multiple times. It's hard form me to explain it well, so I recorded a short video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJJMkAXKNVM

Heres a full javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("#wpwrap").append("<div class=\"avgrund-cover\"></div>");


$("#close-modal").click(function(){

Avgrund.hide("#acf-popup");

});     

(function() {
  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.acfshortcode', {
  init : function(ed, url) {
     ed.addButton('acfshortcode', {
        title : 'Ajax Contact Form',
        image : url+'/../acf-button.png',
        onclick : function() {


           var showname = true;
           var showsubject = true;
           var showbox = true;
           var formwidth = $("#form-width").val();

           Avgrund.show("#acf-popup");

              $("#disable_name").click(function(e){

                 if (showname) {
                    $("#name").parent().slideUp('200');
                    showname = false;
                 }else{
                     $("#name").parent().slideDown('200');
                    showname = true;
                 }

              });




              $("#close-modal").click(function(e){

                 Avgrund.hide("#default-popup");

              });


              $("#disable_subject").click(function(e){

                 if (showsubject) {
                    $("#subject").parent().slideUp('200');
                    showsubject = false;
                 }else{
                    $("#subject").parent().slideDown('200');
                    showsubject = true;
                 }
              });

              $("#disable_box").click(function(e){

                 if (showbox) {
                    $("#acf-contact-form").removeClass('acf-box');
                    showbox = false;
                 }else{
                    $("#acf-contact-form").addClass('acf-box');
                    showbox = true;
                 }

              });

              $("#form-width").keyup(function() {
                formwidth = $("#form-width").val();
                $("#acf-contact-form").css('width', formwidth+'px');
              });

              $("#insert-acf-form").click(function(e){

                 var showname2, showsubject2;

                 if (showname == true) showname2 = 'yes'; else showname2 = 'no';
                 if (showsubject == true) showsubject2 = 'yes'; else showsubject2 = 'no';
                 if (showbox == true) box2 = 'yes'; else box2 = 'no';

                 var name_label = $("#name").val();
                 var email_label = $("#email").val();
                 var subject_label = $("#subject").val();
                 var message_label = $("#message-form").val();
                 var button_label = $("#acf-send-button").text();

                 if (formwidth < 140 ) formwidth = 140;
                 if (formwidth > 1000 ) formwidth = 1000;


                  ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>[acf_contact_form width="'+formwidth+'px" box="'+box2+'" name="'+showname2+'" subject="'+showsubject2+'" name_label="'+name_label+'" email_label="'+email_label+'" subject_label="'+subject_label+'" message_label="'+message_label+'" button_text="'+button_label+'"]</p>');

                 Avgrund.hide("#default-popup");
                 e.preventDefault();
              });



        }
     });
  },
  createControl : function(n, cm) {
     return null;
  },
  getInfo : function() {
     return {
        longname : "Ajax Contact Form Shortcode",
        author : 'Jacek Jagiello',
        version : "1.0"
     };
  }
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add('acfshortcode', tinymce.plugins.acfshortcode);
})();

});
```

Here is function form code above that insert shortcode in the editor:

```
(...) onclick : function() {


       var showname = true;
       var showsubject = true;
       var showbox = true;
       var formwidth = $("#form-width").val();

       Avgrund.show("#acf-popup");

          $("#disable_name").click(function(e){

             if (showname) {
                $("#name").parent().slideUp('200');
                showname = false;
             }else{
                 $("#name").parent().slideDown('200');
                showname = true;
             }

          });




          $("#close-modal").click(function(e){

             Avgrund.hide("#default-popup");

          });


          $("#disable_subject").click(function(e){

             if (showsubject) {
                $("#subject").parent().slideUp('200');
                showsubject = false;
             }else{
                $("#subject").parent().slideDown('200');
                showsubject = true;
             }
          });

          $("#disable_box").click(function(e){

             if (showbox) {
                $("#acf-contact-form").removeClass('acf-box');
                showbox = false;
             }else{
                $("#acf-contact-form").addClass('acf-box');
                showbox = true;
             }

          });

          $("#form-width").keyup(function() {
            formwidth = $("#form-width").val();
            $("#acf-contact-form").css('width', formwidth+'px');
          });

          $("#insert-acf-form").click(function(e){

             var showname2, showsubject2;

             if (showname == true) showname2 = 'yes'; else showname2 = 'no';
             if (showsubject == true) showsubject2 = 'yes'; else showsubject2 = 'no';
             if (showbox == true) box2 = 'yes'; else box2 = 'no';

             var name_label = $("#name").val();
             var email_label = $("#email").val();
             var subject_label = $("#subject").val();
             var message_label = $("#message-form").val();
             var button_label = $("#acf-send-button").text();

             if (formwidth < 140 ) formwidth = 140;
             if (formwidth > 1000 ) formwidth = 1000;


              ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>[acf_contact_form width="'+formwidth+'px" box="'+box2+'" name="'+showname2+'" subject="'+showsubject2+'" name_label="'+name_label+'" email_label="'+email_label+'" subject_label="'+subject_label+'" message_label="'+message_label+'" button_text="'+button_label+'"]</p>');

             Avgrund.hide("#default-popup");
             e.preventDefault();
          });



    }
```

Comment: your youtube video is private

Comment: sorry, now should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your event handlers for your popup in the button's `onclick` handler. That means they'll be added every time you click the button.

In other words, the second time you open the popup by clicking the button, you have two click handlers on `#insert-acf-form`. The third time you'll have three, etc. The same goes for all the other event handlers you assign - but only the click handler will be immediately apparent, because `mceInsertContent` will be called twice.

One solution: Since it appears that the popup is already created before you click the button the first time, you can add all the event handlers for it outside the onclick event handler - i.e., in your initialization code (note, code is only to demonstrate the idea, it is *not* tested and may include syntax errors and whatnot):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("#wpwrap").append("<div class=\"avgrund-cover\"></div>");

   $("#close-modal").click(function() {
      Avgrund.hide("#acf-popup");
   });

   (function() {
      var showname = true;
      var showsubject = true;
      var showbox = true;
      var formwidth = $("#form-width").val();

      // ********** MOVE REGISTRATION OF POPUP EVENT HANDLERS HERE **********

      tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.acfshortcode', {
         init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('acfshortcode', {
               title : 'Ajax Contact Form',
               image : url+'/../acf-button.png',
               onclick : function() {
                  Avgrund.show("#acf-popup");
                  // ************* NOTE, NO EVENT HANDLERS HERE ***********
               }
            });
         },
         createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
         },
         // etc.
      });
   })();
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a check in `onclick` to see if `onclick` has been called before, and not add the event handlers again in that case.

Comment: Hey JimmiTh, thank You so much! Now everything works as it should!